# Is it possible to use SSL with a custom domain on app engine without own certificate?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have an app engine app and I enabled SSL for it (without an own certificate) and it works for the appspot-url like https://myApp.appspot.com. Now I want to use my custom domain like myDomain.com with SSL (e.g. https://myDomain.com). Is this possible without an own certificate like with the appspot domain? I followed this guide (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl?hl=de) and it talks about uploading a certificate. Is that an optional or a mandatory step?

Because if I try to access my domain, I always get an SSL error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading a certificate is mandatory if you want to use SSL for a custom domain. You can find details on SSL handshake at [1].

[1] - http://www.pierobon.org/ssl/ch2/detail.htm

Comment: You can't get a certificate from Google. You can either buy or get one from a free certification authority (however they usually charge for identity validation anyway).